# Error placing variables inside the href using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting an error in php when trying to change the href="" to href=''. Basically I have a code to output a list of products listed in the database. I wanted to create a link on the title like "" the problem is I cannot change the href to include variables. I think this has something to do with the php code but because i'm a beginner in php I have no clue what to do.

Here's the code:

```
$outputList = '';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){ 

$id = $row["id"];
$title = $row["title"];
$location = $row["location"];
$price = $row["price"];
$description = $row["description"];
$map = $row["map"];
$image = $row["image"];

$outputList .= '<div class="ind_result">
            <div class="w-row">
              <div class="w-col w-col-3 w-col-small-6 w-clearfix image">
                <img class="image" src="'.$image.'">
              </div>

              <div class="w-col w-col-9 w-col-small-6 w-clearfix desc"><a class="title" href="">' .$title. '</a>
                <h4 class="price">'.$price.'</h4>
                <h5 class="sub-title">'.$location.'<a href="'.$map.'"><img class="map" src="../images/map.png"></a></h5>
                <p class="description">'.$description.'</p>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>';
```

I've tried using echo instead of the $outputList but only get errors. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**Re-edit:**
This is the code I'm trying to implement:

```
<a class="title" href='example.php?propertyid=$id'>' .$title. '</a>
```

Instead of

```
<a class="title" href="">' .$title. '</a>
```

Comment: What are the contents of "map", and what error are you getting specifically?
Also, if I may make a recommendation of not using echo to write out all your HTML if you can avoid it (and in most cases you can). Just write your HTML as usual and use a few php snippets to echo the variable values in the places you need them. It'll help make debugging a little easier, and make for cleaner, easier to maintain code. Few other things I could nitpick, but that wouldn't help answer your question :)

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast reply. This is the page I'm dealing with now www.yibilia.com/properties.php and the map is basically just the image with a link later to the google api. I wanted to include the option on the title of each listing to "generate" a php page from the template I already made.Hope this helped answer :)

Comment: I see clicking working for the first entry, but not the rest. Is there a specific error message you're getting? Console isn't showing any JS errors.

Comment: I have no errors with the code the way it is above only when I change it to be like <a class="title" href='example.php?propertyid=$id'>' .$title. '</a>

Comment: This right here in your example strikes me: ?propertyid=$id'>' 
When you're using single quotes in PHP, it's not going to automatically substitute your variable value, you have to make sure that's enabled and that you're using double quotes around your string.

Comment: How could I enable it? I mean I see that for the variable to be called it should be inside single quotes right?

Comment: Someone just answered it below :)

Comment: And for the variable to be called it has to be inside double quotes, so for example:

$id=0;
echo "this is some text: $id"//outputs 0
echo 'this is some text: $id'//outputs $id

Comment: I see it now Zarazthuztra, thank you however for the help. Appreciated :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped! And just to clarify why you have to do that: Basically in PHP, the parser will look at what kind of quotes you use to determine whether or not to parse the string for variable substitutions. If there are double quotes, it will parse the string for variables, if single quotes, it won't. It's actually one of those tiny optimizations you can easily make as you write your script as well to use single quotes wherever possible to keep the parser from needlessly parsing strings :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
href="example.php?propertyid=' .$id. '">' .$title. '</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, already tried it and worked. Quite a simple problem now that I see it but couldn't figure it out :) Cheers!